# error: 'void Base::output()' is protected within this context

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

I'm confused about the errors generated by the [following code](http://codepad.org/dGA5KLYs).
In Derived::doStuff, I can access Base::output directly by calling it.

Why can't I create a pointer to `output()` in the same context that I can call `output()`?

(I thought protected / private governed whether you could use a name in a specific context, but apparently that is incomplete?)

Is my fix of writing `callback(this, &Derived::output);` instead of `callback(this, Base::output)` the correct solution?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

template <typename T, typename U>
void callback(T obj, U func)
{
  ((obj)->*(func))();
}

class Base
{
protected:
  void output() { cout << "Base::output" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  void doStuff()
  {
// call it directly:
    output();
    Base::output();

// create a pointer to it:
//    void (Base::*basePointer)() = &Base::output;
// error: 'void Base::output()' is protected within this context
    void (Derived::*derivedPointer)() = &Derived::output;

// call a function passing the pointer:
//    callback(this, &Base::output);
// error: 'void Base::output()' is protected within this context
    callback(this, &Derived::output);
  }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.doStuff();
}
```

Edit: I'd love to know where this is in the stardard, but mostly I'm just trying to wrap my head around the concept.  I think my problem is that `callback` doesn't have access to protected members of `Derived`, but it is able to call `Derived::output` if you pass it a pointer.  How is a protected member of `Derived` that comes from `Derived` different from a protected member of `Derived` that comes from `Base`?

Comment: +1, I am pretty sure that I read the answer recently but can't find it... let's hope some local guru / standardista will be able to enlighten us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it's "because the standard says so." Why? I don't know, I've emailed a couple of the standards guys, but haven't received a response, yet.

Specifically, 11.5.1 (from [C++0x FCD](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf)):

> An additional access check beyond
>   those described earlier in Clause 11
>   is applied when a non-static data
>   member or non-static member function
>   is a protected member of its naming
>   class (11.2)114 As described earlier,
>   access to a protected member is
>   granted because the reference occurs
>   in a friend or member of some class C.
>   If the access is to form a pointer to
>   member (5.3.1), the
>   nested-name-specifier shall denote C
>   or a class derived from C. All other
>   accesses involve a (possibly implicit)
>   object expression (5.2.5). In this
>   case, the class of the object
>   expression shall be C or a class
>   derived from C.

**Edit:**

Also, you'll see that you change the code to the following, according to what the standard specifies, it will compile (and run) cleanly:

```
void (Base::*derivedPointer)() = &Derived::output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm not sure if this is a "Where is this in the standard?" question or a "Why is it designed that way?" question, this answers the latter (I don't have a copy of the standard itself to play with)

I believe this is because a function with protected or friend access to `base` would be able to circumvent access protection by passing the function pointer to methods which should not have access to `base`'s private members.

In this example, `callback` does not have access to `base`, and therefore should not be able to call one of it's private functions.

Comment: I think my problem is that `callback` doesn't have access to protected members of `Derived` either.  How is a protected member of `Derived` that comes from `Derived` different from a protected member of `Derived` that comes from `Base`?